# How to Find 2nd Highest/Lowest Value Across Fields of Record in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I found functions to get the Highest and Lowest values in the link below..

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209857?wa=wsignin1.0

Now I just need to get the second highest/lowest values as well for a function. How can I reference those values? .. If it helps there are only 3 fields I am comparing. The value in the field that isn't referenced by either Minimum or Maximum is the one I need to reference, however someway of specifying 2nd highest/lowest would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL view, you could use a Select statement such as:

```
Select Top 1 yourvalue FROM
(Select Distinct TOP 2 yourvalue
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY yourvalue DESC) Result
ORDER BY yourvalue
```

This will give you the second highest value in the field yourvalue from table yourtable.